# Declined "too broad" flag

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

Trying to understand why was I wrong in casting a "too broad" flag on this question: [Wordpress on subdomain with laravel as frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903376/wordpress-on-subdomain-with-laravel-as-frontend), since a mod declined my flag.

[image: flag history]

When I raised the flag, the edit which added the `.htaccess` hadn't been made yet, but I do not think that edit actually helped the OPs case (the question states that the user is using PHP's built-in server, which doesn't read `.htaccess` at all, something else to address in a potential answer).

I think it is not possible to answer the question without writing the specific router for the questioner, for which there is zero code provided.

You could answer something like:

> If you were not using the built-in server
>
> you could do it like `this` in apache
>
> or like `this` in nginx
>
> or like `this` in IIS;
>
> But if neither option is available or you do not have access to the requisite configuration files you should write a router like
>
> ```
>  `this`
>   [code showing how to build such a route on Laravel,
>   despite no code having been provided by the OP]_
> ```

But I feel that such an answer would be impossible to verify against the OPs requirements, and necessarily too broad for SO scope.

So assuming this question is **not** too broad, why is it not?

The objective, logically, is waste *less* people's time raising unnecessary flags.

**(Brought this up in meta because the "declined" text made me think that a mod had declined my flag directly, instead of it being *disputed* by reviewers; if those labels no longer reflect that distinction, my present question is rather silly.**

**I based my assumption on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212511/348149), but couldn't find any authoritative source to explain the difference between "disputed" and "declined")**

Comment: It wasn't a moderator who declined your flag but [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/18309340). Four reviewers voted to close it and three reviewers voted to leave it open. When three reviewers vote to leave it open, the question leaves the queue. I thought that in cases like this where there isn't any clear consensus, flags were disputed and not declined, but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: @DonaldDuck, I thought so as well, that's the why I was asking it this way. If I saw a "disputed flag" I would not have come to meta to ask about it.

Comment: Note that the question currently is closed as too broad. This means your flag likely was correct. Especially long questions with some code are hard to review, so there are mistakes in the queue.

Comment: Yes. I guess I'll need to delete this question and ask another about the meaning of 'disputed' and 'declined' messages, as this one was asked on the assumption than a mod had declined my flag. Thanks @Erik

Comment: I wouldn't delete this question. It might serve some value as a reference for the future

Comment: The OP edited the question after the flag was raised, so that it was possibly no longer too broad. What happens then? Do the reviewers see the original question or the edited question? Could it happen that different reviewers see different revisions? It would seem to me that only sensible thing the system can do after the edit is to remove the flag and all reviews. But that didn't happen here... so how does the system work (or does it not)?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth What valuable content do you think is there that would be helpful to future readers?

Comment: @Lundin, my question was asked on the assumption than a mod had declined my flag, so your comment about the reviewers actions is no very apropos. And about the edit, I’ve addressed the edit in my question: it was still “too broad” after the edit (as evidenced by being closed right now). Many thanks for your input anyway.

Comment: @Servy People might look for a question when their close flag was declined. They might find this question, and might find it helpful, because the comment thread describes how declines work, and the question shows that it even happens with good flags.

Comment: @yivi I'm just curious about how the system works, because I can't make sense of it.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth There are dozens and dozens of posts of people asking why their flag was declined, and FAQ posts that are *far* more effective in describing how flag declines work.

Comment: Thanks @Servy. Can you point me at one of those FAQs that describe properly how declining works? I have another question where that answer would be relevant. In this one, I even point to one answer of yours where you say that flags are "declined" by diamond mods, which was the  assumption that triggered this question. As I said, I wouldn't have asked the question if I thought it was the community was the one doing the "declining".

Comment: @Servy I agree a faq (or a decent summary answer on this question) might be desired, but in a quick search I couldn't find a post that better described the situation than this one, hence my desire to preserve it. Of course, you've been around longer, and if you have a decent dupe/faq, feel free to share it.

Comment: Just to note that mod declines will be of the format: "declined - some message for declining here" rather than just "declined" by itself...

Comment: Thanks @JonClements, I wasn't aware of that. I was going on the "if 'declined' => mod" mantra; which was, evidently, **wrong**. I think that a clarification of how those messages work and what they mean would not be amiss. It's not a big deal, but there is nothing wrong in adding a bit more documentation, right? When I flag I do it to try to help the system, the better feedback I have the better flags I'll raise in the future.

Comment: @yivi indeed and thanks for doing so. I have a feeling this *is* documented somewhere - it's just that that somewhere isn't easy to find...

Comment: @JonClements There are a few posts linked in my [other, related question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361584/when-are-flags-disputed-and-when-declined) where I think in the end is possible to piece everything together. The feeling is that getting to that info is rather **hard**, when it should be easy (to help avoid questions such as this one). At least add a q&a documenting all the cases, and link them from the FAQ index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This question was asked based on a false assumption.

The flag was not declined by a diamond mod, but by the community on [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/18309340).

The message "declined" made me think it was a mod the one responsible for declining (based on answers like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212511/348149)), but I was mistaken.

Apparently I was not alone in thinking that when the community rejected a flag a "disputed" message was shown. Maybe a better FAQ or documentation in the help center would be needed.